# Help building a list based on a enumeration

Tags: c#

I have an enumeration:

```
public enum SomeEnum
{
  A = 2,
  B = 4,
  C = 8
  D = 16 
}

SomeEnum e1 = SomeEnum.A | SomeEnum.B
```

Now I want to have a List of enum values, so e1 would be:

```
2, 4
```

So I have:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();

foreach(SomeEnum se in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)))
{

  if(.....)
  {
     list.Add( (int)se );
  }


}
```

I need help with the if statement above.

**Update**

How can I build a list of ints representing the flags set in the enum `e1`?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here.. please reformat your post into a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to add the value if it's in e1?

Then you can use the [HasFlag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx) method in .NET 4.

```
if(e1.HasFlag(se))
{
    list.Add( (int)se );
}
```

If you're not using .net the equivilant is `e1 & se == se`

Also by convention you should mark your enum with the [FlagsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) and it should be in plural form (SomeEnums)

Answer (score 4):

I suspect you want:

```
if ((e1 & se) != 0)
```

On the other hand, using [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) you could write:

```
foreach (SomeEnum se in Enums.GetValues<SomeEnum>())
{
    if (se.HasAny(e1))
    {
        list.Add((int) se);
    }
}
```

Or using LINQ:

```
List<int> list = Enums.GetValues<SomeEnum>()
                      .Where(se => se.HasAny(e1))
                      .Select(se => (int) se)
                      .ToList();
```

(It would be nice if you could use `e1.GetFlags()` or something to iterate over each bit in turn... will think about that for another release.)

Comment: Doing your 1st suggestion doesn't work, getting a type issue: cannot apply operands of type & ... with type bool.

Comment: @codecompleting: Probably just a precedence issue - try the edited version (just added brackets).

Comment: Well I went the linq route, and used HasFlag, not sure if that will workign testing it now.

Comment: @codecompleting: Should do. I just prefer Unconstrained Melody for type safety, compatibility with .NET 2, and because I wrote it :)

Comment: I also prefer it for precisely the same set of reasons :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if((int)(e1 & se) > 0)
```

That should do it

Answer (score 0):

this would work

```
if((int)se==(int)SomeEnum.A||(int)se==(int)SomeEnum.B )
      {
         list.Add( (int)se );
      }
```